# ¿Puedo crear archivos js que ejecuten comandos de mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

El asunto es que quiero crear unos scripts que reciban parámetros para posteriormente realizar operaciones como CRUD.

Por ejemplo, el tener una aplicación desarrollada en x lenguaje, al momento de querer hacer una operación a la DB, se envíe la solicitud al archivo que contiene el javascript y comandos mongo. **Ejemplo_mongo.js:**

```
var x = "valor obtenido desde el archivo solicitante, puede ser un documento (formato JSON)";

db.mi_coleccion.insert(x);
```

Comment: Necesitas un Restful o estas con Node?

Comment: Estoy con Node usando Express. Restful no lo conocía. Estoy en etapa de investigación para las mejores alternativas.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, me imagino que necesitas que tu aplicacion reciba parametros de una aplicacion externa, una vez que recibio los parametros mediante Node realizar el metodo CRUD. Es correcto??? Si es asi busca Node socket IO

Comment: Sí, en esencia es separar todas las operaciones en DB en archivos independientes para que puedan ser reutilizados por diferentes aplicaciones que lo requieran. Voy a revisar eso que comentas. Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Tengo entendido que con Express hay una configuracion para conectarse a mongo creo que se llama "mongoose" y para tener crear un CRUD se puede usar las funciones create, find, remove, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si quieres utilizar mongo en un archivo js es necesario que utilices un driver
ya que puedes esta programando en **x** maquina pero no estas conectado a mongo

primero mongo es un sgbd y cuando lo instalas puedes estar corriendo el servidor 
que guarda los datos y no estar utilizando el cliente el cual consulta tu información,
¿cual es el cliente? en mi caso es la terminal (cuando ejecutas el comando `mongo` y no `mongod` el cual es del servidor)  en otros casos es `robomongo`, etc..

los clientes ejecutan una conexión a 127.0.0.1:27017 y pasan las consultas que tengas al servidor para que te retorne la información

entonces como le comento es necesario que utilice un `driver` como el nativo de mongo para [nodejs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/)  o el driver de [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs) ahí, tu ya puedes decir que realice la conexión a una determinada db y realizar consultas como si fuera una terminal, ya si quieres hacer un programa en cualquier lenguaje, tienes que realizar un servidor y crear un `api` (pero eso es otro tema).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Esta pregunta la hice hace tiempo cuando apenas estaba investigando. Actualmente ya tengo la solución haciendo una api restfull con nodejs y express, y cuando hice la pregunta estaba más metido en mongodb por terminal :P Saludos